# Add files in flows

Tags: community, visual-workflow, files

I am trying to add txt (or other files with other extensions) in File Upload component in the flow.
I need to add a few files and I set {!$GlobalConstant.True}
I am trying to set extensions (.txt, .pdf or ".txt") in this box or leave it empty
[image]

But I receive this kind of error in SF community (unable\impossible to add files)
[image]

Do we need additional actions?

Comment: Which community template are you using? Make sure the community template you are using supports Lightning File Upload.

Comment: @Sneh this files were uploaded by flow... or community template has impact on it?

Comment: Thx for the ide